# Prove that $\operatorname{range} T = W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T: V \to W$ be a linear transformation of vector spaces. Assume $(w_1,\ldots,w_m)$ is a spanning sequence of $W$ and $w_j \in \operatorname{range} T$ for every $j.$ Prove that $\operatorname{range} T = W.$

Take a vector $w \in W.$ Then $w = c_1w_1 + \cdots + c_m w_m$ for $c_j \in \mathbb{F}$ since $\operatorname{span} (w_1,\ldots,w_m) = W.$ By assumption, every $w_j \in \operatorname{range} T,$ and so $w \in \operatorname{range } T,$ meaning that $W \subset \operatorname{range} T.$ Since $\operatorname{range} T \subset W$ by definition, it follows that $\operatorname{range} T = W. \Box$

Am I missing any details in the above proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that ${\rm range}(T)$ is a subspace of $W$. Since it contains a spanning set for $W$, it must be all of $W$.